# Return item in array field mongodb with pipeline operators

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using something similar to below right now and it works and grabs what I need:

```
    state: { 
        $filter: { 
            input: "$location.address_components",
            as: "address_comp",
            cond: { $in: ["administrative_area_level_1", "$$address_comp.types"]}
        }
    },
```

In my use case it's not always guaranteed.  In this case I am doing the same for `country` and `postal` with different equality checks for the condition.  However, what I am left with is a `state` field on my returned document that is an array of max size 1 with an object inside.

I'd ideally like to have that field just be the object itself rather than an array with the specified object returned by the `filter` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to guess what your entire aggregation pipeline looks like, but I will assume that your final stage yields something like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key1": "value1",
    "state": [
      {
        "somekey": "dssdd"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In this case you would just need to `$unwind` the `state` path. So, again I assume that your last stage is a `$project`:

```
    {
        "$project": { 
            ...
            ...
            state: { 
                $filter: { 
                    input: "$location.address_components",
                    as: "address_comp",
                    cond: { $in: ["administrative_area_level_1", "$$address_comp.types"]}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$state"
    }
```

The result will be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "key": 1,
    "state": {
      "somekey": "dssdd"
    }
  }
]
```